# What is Weblogic's frontend host property used for?

Tags: weblogic

It is unclear when it would be useful to set the "frontend host" setting in Weblogic 11g. Can anyone please tell me why I should set this? I do have a load balancer in front of weblogic that will mask the ip address. Is that when I would use it? What will setting this actually do? The documentation doesnt provide any clarity here.

Answer (score 0):

"frontend host" of weblogic is used when there is no load balancer is used for a weblogic cluster, In this case without any load balancer IP and PORT you can assign an IP and Port of an address which will work as an exposed URL for clients.